# Java Spring 4 REST Service error 404 page not found

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I am trying to realize my first REST service with Spring, Java et Tomcat. The aim of my project is just realize an url that return data formated with JSON.
This is the different elements of my project :

pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.incvision.utils</groupId>
      <artifactId>springexample</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>springexample Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <properties>
       <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
       <jackson.library>2.6.3</jackson.library>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>springexample</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

web.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
     version="3.0"> 
       <display-name>
         Archetype Created Web Application
       </display-name>
       <servlet>
         <servlet-name>
           mvc-dispatcher2
         </servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
         </servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher2</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/resthandler/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Servlet mvc-dispatcher2 definition => mvc-dispatcher2-servlet.xml :

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context- 
                                                             3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base- 
                           package="com.incvision.utils.resthandler" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Controllers definition :
HelloWorld2Controller.java

```
    package com.incvision.utils.resthandler;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/helloapp")
    public class HelloWorld2Controller {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String hello(ModelMap model) {
          model.addAttribute("msg", "JCG Hello World!");
          return "helloWorld";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/displaymessage/{msg}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String displayMessage(@PathVariable String msg, ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
            return "helloWorld";
        }
   }
```

SaveImageAjaxController.java

```
    package com.incvision.utils.resthandler;

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.util.Base64;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    import com.incvision.utils.general.AjaxResponseBody;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/webagent")
    public class SaveImageAjaxController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/saveimage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       @ResponseBody
       public AjaxResponseBody getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestBody String imageData) {

         System.out.println("Appel de  SaveImageAjaxController à /webagent/saveimage");

         AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();

         byte[] data = 
         Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageData.getBytes());

         try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/pjdoe/Documents/moninamge.png")) {
           fos.write(data);
           fos.close(); 
         } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        result.setCode("200");
        result.setMsg("L'image a été sauvegardé.");

        return result;
      }
    }
```

A jsp : HelloWorld.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Spring 4.0.2 MVC web service</h1>
        <h3>Your Message : ${msg}</h3> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

I have two services. The first service displays an hello message with parameters. It is mapped on the url http://localhost:8080/SpringRestHandler/resthandler/helloapp/hello
The second service save an image uploaded with ajax. It is mapped on the url http://localhost:8080/SpringRestHandler/resthandler/webagent/saveimage

The two requests retrieve a 404 error. The requests are executed with Postman.
What is the problem in my implementation ?
Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Are there any logs that provide some more information to isolate the cause?

Comment: have you provided `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and base package `<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.common.controller" />` [https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/]